# How can I generate camera shake?

Tags: animation, game-engine, camera

I would like to generate camera shake in either a render or in BGE.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Well, the extremely lame way to do this would be to just move the camera; in an animation you could just take the graph editor, insert some keys, then just move the values ever so slightly around so that it jitters.

Comment: Related: http://www.creativeshrimp.com/handheld-camera-tutorial.html

Comment: this plugin https://blendermarket.com/products/quake-motion-camera does the magic and its not an affiliate link its just a suggestion for you if you want to try it out, adds camera shake with one click of a button

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could insert a single keyframe for the location on the camera (if you dont have any movement) and then, in the the graph editor, add a noise modifier to the curves in the properties panel (N key). Adjust the values of the modifier so you can get the intensity and movement that you like.

Comment: Remember to add one noise modifier to each channel.

Answer (score 12):

## Recorded hand held shake

- *Select | Select Camera and (optionally) View | Camera* or <kbd>numpad 0</kbd>.
- In the Timeline window:
- Enable *Frame | Auto-Keyframing Mode | Add & Replace* or simply use the [image: record] button.
- Hit play (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and enter trackball rotation <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or grab <kbd>G</kbd> mode.
- Move your pointing device around to generate the shake.

Note: You can get a more controlled (or violent) effect with different frame rate during recording.

Answer (score 11):

As has been mentioned - fcurves modified with noise can do this.

For the game engine you can use an action with noise too (access action through the action actuator).

Note that while noise modified fcurves on camera are a start, you may want to have a very basic camera rig, I've seen this done before where an empty parent controls the camera, and there are 2 children, one the camera, another empty object with noise applied. The camera constrains to the noise empty using `Copy Transforms` constraint.

This has the advantage you can do regular (non-noisy) animation to the parent, and the constraint can be animated so you can adjust the noise level over time. - Of course if you wanted to go further you could blend different types of noise easily by adding more empties+constraints and blending those in too (to simulate different terrain).

Since the game engine wont do constraints, something more complex like this would need to use python scripting.