# How would I go about making a character have that twitchy/ jerky movement?

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm working on an animation with a model of a monster and I want it to have that Twitchy/Jerky movement to give it that creepy and disturbing look. Any advice on this will be of much help.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Noise modifier for the keyframes? It will make it shake

Comment: I haven't, I will look into that

Comment: if you don't understand how it works, please tell, here is a tuto for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-43Dw0Lj08s

Comment: I will thank you

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209512/how-do-i-give-a-keyframed-object-a-bit-of-vibration-shaking-when-its-at-the-des https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107102/how-to-add-bumpiness-to-a-car-roller-coaster-motion https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/581/how-can-i-generate-camera-shake/